# Internet does not work even though Gmail keeps on working

Tags: windows-7, internet, internet-connection

​​Sometime my internet does not work even though Gmail keeps on working.
How can I recover from this position without starting my machine.

Comment: We're going to need more information. Are you saying you aren't able to reach any website except gmail?

Comment: By changing your DNS. Try using 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 in your pc.